# virsh get disk location of all VMs in a Array

Tags: arrays, bash, virsh

```
for i in $(virsh list --all | awk '{print $2}'|grep -v Name);
  do
    virsh domblklist $i --details | awk '{print $4}'|grep -v Source;
  done
```

I get

```
/sdc/kvm_strage/vm1.qcow2
/sdc/kvm_strage/vm1_1.qcow2
-


/sdc/kvm_strage/vm2.qcow2
-


/sdc/kvm_strage/vm3.qcow2
/sdc/kvm_strage/vm3_1.qcow2
-
```

But I want to get the path in a array and exclude the `"-"` like

```
my_array=(/sdc/kvm_strage/vm1.qcow2 /sdc/kvm_strage/vm1_1.qcow2 /sdc/kvm_strage/vm2.qcow2 /sdc/kvm_strage/vm3.qcow2 /sdc/kvm_strage/vm3_1.qcow2)
```

How to do that?

Comment: Add output of `virsh list --all` and your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way:

```
declare -a my_array=($(for vm in $(virsh list --all --name); do
    virsh domblklist $vm --details | awk '/disk/{print $4}'
done))
```

EDIT: I just noticed I missed a pair of parenthesis when setting the value of `my_array`.

Comment: I think you missed the header lines to skip from the `virsh` output.

Comment: I didn't. The ```--name``` list just the domain names.

Comment: very nice. is there a way to exclude some vm?

Comment: @fteinz, you can define an exclusion list and check if ```${vm}``` is part of that list inside the ```for``` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the 2 header lines with `tail --lines=+3`, to avoid capturing the column titles and dash line separator header.

This is how a `virsh list --all` look like:

2 header lines to skip with `tail --lines=+3`:

```
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

Data to parse:

```
 1     openbsd62                      running
 2     freebsd11-nixcraft             running
 3     fedora28-nixcraft              running
```

After it skip the header line of the domains list, the script below iterates over each domain in a `while read` loop witch receives its data from the `virsh list --all | tail --lines=+3 | awk '{print $2}'`

Then inside the while loop, it maps the output of `virsh domblklist "$domain" --details | tail --lines=+3 | awk '{print $4}'` into the temporary file-mapped array `MAPFILE`;
and add the `MAPFILE` array entries to `my_array`

After execution, `my_array` contains all block devices from all domains.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a my_array=() # array of all block devices

# Iterate over domains that are read from the virsh list
while IFS= read -r domain; do
  mapfile < <( # capture devices list of domain into MAPFILE
    # Get block devices list of domain
    virsh domblklist "$domain" --details |

      # Start line 3 (skip 2 header lines)
      tail --lines=+3 |

        # Get field 4 s value
        awk '{print $4}'
  )
  my_array+=( "${MAPFILE[@]}" ) # Add the block devices paths list to my_array
done < <( # Inject list of domains to the while read loop
  # List all domains
  virsh list --all --name
)
```